# Jquery UI combo box - loading from remote url

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, combobox

I use jquery-ui plugin and I need to load data from a remote url. I used following code and it doesnt work. Can any one help me.

```
        $( "#metadata" ).combobox({ 
            source: "metadata/retrievejson",
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you link to the plugin you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should look at this [link in the doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp). It shows how to retrieve data asynchronously.

your code should look something like this

```
$( "#metadata" ).combobox({ 
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function( data ) {
                     response(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete plugin works as stated by Amin Eshaq,
however, the combobox ([1](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)) does not have support for remote data, since it's using selectbox.

You could consider extending autocomplete with a button triggering the search event with the text from the autocomplete field.

```
.autocomplete("search", [value])
```